# Pandas not compiling database properly

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am trying to compile data I am pulling from a csv database that has the data broken down into month by month. Some months don't have any data and thus don't have a csv file. However, my code **isn't compiling the code and exporting it as a csv file** for some reason. It only pulls the first link and stops

reference link: http://pubdata.mlml.calstate.edu/mlml_last/weather/2010-05.csv

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import numpy as np
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

#Checks / corrects entered day values
def check_day(d):
    try:
        if d>31 or d<1:
            print("day input not valid")
        elif len(str(d))==1:
            d='0'+str(d)
        else:
            pass
        return str(m)
    except:
        print("day input not valid")
 
#Checks / corrects entered month value
def check_month(m):
    try:
        if m >12 or m<1:
            print("input not valid")
        elif len(str(m)) ==1:
            m='0'+str(m)
        else:
            pass
        return str(m)

    except:
        print("month input not valid")
    
#Checks / corrects entered year value
c_year=int(datetime.date.today().strftime("%Y"))
def check_year(y):
    try:
        if len(str(y))==2:
            if int(y)>int(str(c_year)[-2:]):
                y='19'+str(y)
            else:
                y='20'+str(y)
        elif int(y)>c_year or int(y)<int(2000):
            print("data only available from "+str(2000)+" to "+str(c_year))
        else:
            pass
        return str(y)
    except:
        print("year input not valid")

#Testing block
f_d=int(4)
f_m=int(5)
f_y=int(2010)

t_d=int(17)
t_m=int(10)
t_y=int(2010)
#

f_date=datetime.datetime(f_y,f_m,f_d)
t_date=datetime.datetime(t_y,t_m,t_d)

def d_strip(x):
    return datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
dfs=[]
print("compiling in process, please wait a moment.")
while f_date<=t_date:
    f_date += relativedelta(months=1)
    y=str(d_strip(str(f_date)).year)
    m=str(d_strip(str(f_date)).month-1)
    year=check_year(int(y))
    month=check_month(int(m))
    try:
        dfs.append(pd.read_csv('http://pubdata.mlml.calstate.edu/mlml_last/weather/'+year+"-"+month+".csv"))
    except:
        pass

c_df = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)

c_df['pst_time']=pd.to_datetime(c_df['pst_time'])
c_df[(c_df['pst_time']>=f_date)&(c_df['pst_time']<=t_date)]

c_df.to_csv("/Users/USERNAME/Downloads/comp_data.csv")

print("Done! Check your downloads folder for the csv file.")
```

Comment: this seems like unusually complicated code just to loop over years and months. Which files are you trying to download?

Comment: A lot of the code is for user input to customize which files they want to iterate over. for now I skip the user input section for testing purposes. See the `testing block` section of code for what the user would enter

Comment: What exactly happens? Do you get an output CSV containing only one month of data? Or no CSV file at all?

Comment: yes, I get a csv file containing only one month of data, the first month specifically.

Comment: I can't replicate this: when I run your code on Google Colab, I get data from May through October 2010.  Could it be that (1) from your location there are problems downloading some of the files from the web (but then it's odd the first month would work), or (2) what you're running is slightly different than the code posted here?